# In a while loop, how can I click a link in a list webelement only once?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click links displayed in a list web element only once

I have dynamic elements that keep popping up on a page and the whole program is just about clicking the pop-up links and opening new windows so that I can perform some action in the newly opened windows. I have tried the code attached below and even made use of the break statement just before the end of my while statement(which is always true) but it just solves the problem only once and stops the loop. The small code attached below clicks on the links infinitely by opening new windows, without stopping. Please help me to click the links in the list web element only once and keep the code running in the while loop

```
Actions newwin = new Actions(driver);

boolean clicked = true;

while (clicked) {
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    List < WebElement > fungua = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("309"));
    //THEN CLICK ON THE SUBMIT BUTTON 
    fungua.forEach(e - > {
        newwin.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(e).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
    });
}
```

I am not an expert in this field but I have managed to have all the other code work as expected but the problem I have above just prevents me from moving on. I have tried this for many days and I thought you might help in running the code above infinitely but click the links in the list web element only once. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never update `clicked` inside of your `while` loop.

Comment: Also, I didn't get why you need `fungua.get(0);` inside of your `forEach` method.

Comment: oh sorry, the fungua.get(0) was not supposed to be there, I was just trying to see if it made anything happen, I have edited it now. check it

Comment: Hello  Mensur Qulami, how do I that? please tell me. I once tried it to make clicked=false, and the loop stopped from there

Comment: Don't you want that? Happening only once and stopping after that?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, I want it to stop after doing that action of clicking but I want the code to keep searching for other elements that might pop up in the page and click on them.When I put clicked=false, it will no longer search and click the other elements that might pop up.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your problem. So in your loop it refreshes the page, searches for all elements of a particular type and then asks to click on each of them. After doing this it refreshes the page and repeats the process? Why all the refreshes? Why is your loop infinite in this case?

Comment: Hello AJC24, Yes.Exactly as you've described it till the "why all the refreshes".I was refreshing it to check for new elements. I know it seems dumb but if you have a better solution please help . It is infinite so that it can keep on checking/listening for new elements and click them whenever they appear.Please propose something